# Returning a List<String> so that caller can not modify it

Tags: c#

I am exposing `List<string>` as a property, but want to avoid its modification outside the object. What is the best way to do it in C#, Do I create a new copy of `List<string>` or do something else..

Comment: Don't expose it as a `List<string>`?

Comment: Do you only wish to prevent modification of the list, or modification to the objects inside the list as well?

Comment: Note that unless you make a full deep copy of the objects in the list, copying the list doesn't solve your problem if the elements of the list are reference types and you merely copy the references from the internal list to the returned list.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible with the `List<T>` type. The best way is exposing a proeprty of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` type ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132476.aspx)).

You may consider it explicitly implements `ICollection` interface which exposes `Add()` method but do not worry and keep in mind that:

> **ICollection.Add**
>
> Adds an item to the ICollection. This implementation always throws NotSupportedException.

BTW, why you need `List<T>` type? Perhaps exposing a property of type `IEnumerable<T>` is enought? Which specific functionality of the `List<T>` are you using, perhaps built in sort/search methods? Anyway if you really need `List<T>` - you can use it as a type for property backing field and transform it either via `ReadonlyCollection<T>(IList<T> list)` constructor or using `List<T>.AsReadonly()` method call, really no difference since `AsReadonly()` is a single line method which does `return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(this);`.

Comment: This does NOT satisfy the request to return a `List<string>`.

Comment: He stated that it is not possible to return an unmodifiable List<string> object.

Comment: @Blam: He edited that in. One of those ghost edits. I hate them.

Comment: @Blam: sorry I've added this after Jason's comment

Comment: @Jason: thanks for pointing to this and sorry for the late comment

Answer (score 2):

Add `AsReadOnly()` to the end of your list

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> test = new List<string> {"test"}.AsReadOnly();
```

Answer (score 1):

Return `IEnumberable<String>`. That way even if you change your implementation(you may feel using `XYZ` datastructure makes the program more efficient), the callers does not have to change code.

I am just curious to know why do you want to enforce such a constraint. If possible please give the community more details, they may help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        _MyProperty = new List<string>();
        _MyProperty.Add("Test 1");
        _MyProperty.Add("Test 2");
    }
    private List<string> _MyProperty;
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> MyProperty 
    {
        get { return _MyProperty.AsReadOnly(); }
    }        
}
```

Comment: In this case you still able calling `MyProperty.Add("new item")`

Comment: @Firoz: `obj.MyProperty.Add(x)` doesn't require that `MyProperty` have a setter.  The getter returns the private list -- the *real* list, with a *public* `Add` method -- so you can add stuff to it at will.

Comment: @cHao: You are right. MyProperty still allow to add items in the collection. To fix it, I modified my code.